# PHP and selected option menu

Tags: php

Hello I created a menu from a table. I added to the table employee the user none to make it the default value in the option menu. The problem is that I dont know how to add the none user as the default value in the option menu. Here is what I have:

```
$query = "SELECT UserName FROM employee where Classification_ClassificationID = '2'"; 
     $result = queryMysql($query);

        if (!queryMysql($query)) {
 "Query fail: $query<br />" .
        mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
                        }
else
{

<select name = "UserName", "Name" size = "1">'; // or name="toinsert[]"
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['UserName']) . '" >' 
  . htmlspecialchars($row['UserName'])
  . '</option>';
```

Comment: Just add a `<option>None</option>` manually after you open the select.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. but that code is frickin' ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo `<option selected="selected">Non User</option>` before the while loop. Also read comments [@Cybernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599951/php-and-selected-option-menu/4599978#comment-5054370) .

Comment: @Cybernate - Elaborate please.

Comment: As per OP "added to the table employee the user none to make it the default value in the option menu", hence I was suggesting to remove this entry from the table since there is no need for the entry anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>

<?php
if (!queryMysql($query)) {
    "Query fail: $query<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}
else
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $selected = '';
    if($row['Username']=='none') $selected = ' selected="selected"';
        echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['UserName']).'"'.$selected.'>'.htmlspecialchars($row['UserName']).'</option>';
    }
 }
 ?>
</select>
```